# Render components based on what a function returns

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, conditional-rendering

I have a function that checks if a prescription has expired or not. I map an array of prescriptions and show them within a table component.

How do I show the component only if the function returns "Active"? What's the syntax to implement this?

Here's my code:

Function for the Active/Expired check

```
const datePrescription = (prescriptionDate, prescriptionExpirationDate) => {
    let prescriptionIssueDate = new Date(prescriptionDate)
    // add the days the prescription is meant to be active of to the original prescription date
    prescriptionIssueDate.setDate(prescriptionIssueDate.getDate() + prescriptionExpirationDate);
    // get current time
    let currentDate = new Date()

 // compare current date with expiration to determine if the prescription has expired
    if (currentDate > prescriptionIssueDate) {
      return "Expired"
    } else {
      return "Active"
    }
  }
```

The component:

```
<Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell><strong>Patient</strong></TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right"><strong>Patient Diagnosis</strong></TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right"><strong>Issuing Date</strong></TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right"><strong>Issuing Doctor</strong></TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right"><strong>Pharmaceutical Drug</strong></TableCell>
        <TableCell align="center"><strong>Action</strong></TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
      {prescriptions.map((prescription) => (
    <Slide direction="up" in={prescriptions} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
    <TableRow key={prescription._id}>
          <TableCell>{prescription.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{prescription.diagnosis}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{new Date(prescription.prescriptionDate).toDateString()}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{prescription.doctor}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{prescription.drug}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="center">
              <Tooltip title="Details">
                    <IconButton aria-label="details" component={Link} to={`/prescriptions/${prescription._id}`}>
                        <NoteAddIcon />
                     </IconButton>
                    </Tooltip> 
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        </Slide>
      ))}
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
```

Comment: `.filter` the array before `.map`ping it

Comment: how do i exactly do that though, I just want to show it based on "Expired" or "Active" return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter the array and then map it to JSX:

```
{
    prescriptions
        .filter((prescription) => {
            return datePrescription(
                prescription.prescriptionDate,
                prescription.prescriptionExpirationDate
            ) === 'Active';
        })
        .map((prescription) => (
            <Slide direction="up" in={prescriptions} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>

            </Slide>
        ))
}
```

Comment: Looks good, understandable and works, thank you very much